c# How do I get screenshot without Winform on it?
I want to get screenshot behind current winform. For this I am using a method like this:
private void GetScreen(string file_path)
{
    Opacity = 0;
    var rect = new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Height);
    using var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb);
    using var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, Size);
    Opacity = .99D;
    bmp.Save(file_path, ImageFormat.Tiff);
}

This snipped code works correctly. But I feel very uncomfortable to set opacity. Because when it works, it feels like the form is constantly flickering. The same feeling happens when I hide/show the form. I want the form to appear on the front side all the time. But as I run the method, I want it to take a screenshot behind the form without the form elements and save it. For example, there is a program called AnyMP4 Screen Recorder. It can take screenshots inside the frame without the need for show/hide operations.
How can I do this?

Is using winforms a requirement?

@Progman - Because I am coding for my hobbies, for my own business and I am familiar with winforms. Is there any other way you can suggest?

When you have a non-rectangular window (see Region property), the OS has to draw all windows behind yours before asking yours to draw.  So you can capture that image during your OnPaintBackground event

use below line
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
and take the screen shot.

That's also going to cause flashing.

I wish you had bothered to read my question.
